# Is a fake context needed to create modern OpenGL context?

Tags: c, opengl

According to [this page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)#Proper_Context_Creation) (and several others) you need to create a dummy window, then a dummy legacy context, then use `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` to create a modern context.

However I tried using the old way with `wglCreateContext` and loading functions manually:

```
glCreateShader = wglGetProcAddress("glCreateShader");
glShaderSource = wglGetProcAddress("glShaderSource");
glCompileShader = wglGetProcAddress("glCompileShader");
...etc for all other functions that I need
```

Then I checked the context version:

```
int minor;
int major;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &major);
glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &minor);
printf("%d.%d\n", major, minor);
```

And I got "4.6". Why isn't the version something like 2.0 and why is the fake context thing needed?

Comment: Try to get a Core context using the same method :)

Comment: So the trick is done to get a particular version? I was under the impression that to create a modern context at all you had to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to limit your application to never using WGL extensions (ie: you can't do things like control vsync, use more advanced pixel formats, create [robust](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Robust_access_context) or [debug](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) OpenGL contexts, or any number of other tools) and always using a compatibility context, then yes, you can get away with not using the more modern context creation APIs. But there's no reason to impose such limits on your program.

Comment: I was able to use `wglSwapInterval(1)` to control vsync, I got the function with `wglGetProcAddress("wglSwapIntervalEXT")`. Why could I do this?

Comment: @nexide: And how did you know that this function pointer would be legitimate? Did you check to see if the extension was advertised? You don't just go around querying function pointers and assuming that the pointer they return is valid if it isn't NULL.

Comment: Is it ok to do `wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB")` with the dummy context though? In the example I saw you create a dummy context -> load `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` -> create a new context -> load the rest of the function. But `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` needs `WGL_ARB_create_context_profile`, and to check that you also need `WGL_ARB_extensions_string`, at what point you can be sure the function pointer is correct?

Comment: @nexide: "*Is it ok to do wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB") with the dummy context though?*" How do you know that this function is available for use without looking at the extension list? You have to look at the WGL extensions to find that out, and that requires `WGL_ARB_extensions_string` which is advertised by `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`.

Comment: I can't find `WGL_ARB_extensions_string` with `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`, but I can find it with `wglGetExtensionsStringEXT()`.

Comment: I think I got it `Applications should call wglGetProcAddress to see whether or not
    wglGetExtensionsStringEXT is supported.` https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/WGL_EXT_extensions_string.txt